# Проверка на заполненность listModel JList

Tags: java, swing, model

Имеется JList, с моделью

```
DefaultListModel listModel = formLogin.listModelLogin;
```

В классе `formLogin` на кнопке висит `listModelLogin.add(0,user);`. То есть, при заходе кидает логин в ячейку с нулевым индексом. Возможно ли проверять, сколько ячеек занято и вписывать в первую свободную? (Предполагается, что форма логина будет запускать не единожды, соответственно) Благодарю!

Comment: [defaultListModel.addElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement-E-)?

Comment: Прошу прощения?